# get last update of google sheet in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get the last update time of the sheet from within an apps script of that sheet. I tried looking at the docs and couldn't find mention of this and DocsList which apparently could be used to return the revision history (though I only want the last change date) is no longer functioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DocsList is deprecated, use [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) instead.

Try the following code:

```
// Replace 'SPREADSHEET_KEY_HERE' with the key of spreadsheet of which you want to get the date and time

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var dateCreated = getCreatedDateTime('SPREADSHEET_KEY_HERE');
  s.getRange('A1').setValue(dateCreated);

  var lastUpdated = getLastUpdatedTime('SPREADSHEET_KEY_HERE');
  s.getRange('A2').setValue(lastUpdated);
};

function getLastUpdatedTime(SpreadsheetId) {
  return DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetId).getLastUpdated();
};

function getCreatedDateTime(SpreadsheetId) {
  return DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetId).getDateCreated();
};
```

Comment: How do you deploy and run this for multiple rows in a google sheet? I also want this to run for all non empty rows, or at least select which rows this runs on.